# Where is ${SHDP_AMSERVICE_PORT} for DefaultMindAppmasterServiceClient defined?

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

In the [YARN Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE-hadoop24/reference/html/yarn.html), Section 11.12.2 Partitioning on `Configuring Container` the 
`DefaultMindAppmasterServiceClient` is setup by the following:

```
<yarn-int:amservice-client
    service-impl="org.springframework.yarn.integration.ip.mind.DefaultMindAppmasterServiceClient"
    host="${SHDP_AMSERVICE_HOST}"
    port="${SHDP_AMSERVICE_PORT}" />
```

How is the port `SHDP_AMSERVICE_PORT` defined for the `amservice`?

Comment: @kamran-ahmed: For reference, when making an edit that adds hidden HTML, make a note that it was already there beforehand.  When looking at it in the review queue, it isn't obvious where it came from in rendered output mode.

Answer (score 0):

Your link includes this,

> Through Spring's property placeholder [support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer), [SpEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE-hadoop24/reference/html/docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) and the [environment abstraction](http://spring.io/blog/2011/06/09/spring-framework-3-1-m2-released/) (available in Spring 3.1). one can externalize environment specific properties from the main code base easing the deployment across multiple machines.

It also mentions support for `Properties` files. But it appears that it supports environment variables. On *nix type systems you might define it like

```
export SHDP_AMSERVICE_PORT=1234 # for example
```

On Windows that would look like

```
set SHDP_AMSERVICE_PORT 1234
```

**Edit**

Based on your comment I downloaded it and it's used in `container-context.xml` under

```
yarn/yarn/custom-amservice/src/main/resources/container-context.xml
yarn/yarn/batch-files/src/main/resources/container-context.xml
yarn/yarn/batch-partition/src/main/resources/container-context.xml
```

Nothing defines it, so it uses a default value. You can override it as above.

Comment: I'm using the yarn examples in the spring-hadoop-samples-2.0.0.RC4. These examples work for me building them with gradle, but I do not understand where SHDP_AMSERVICE_PORT is defined as I do not have it defined as an environment variable.